# How to place a div next to a centered div

Tags: html, css

How I can place a div next to a div that is centered on the page, thus:

```
.firstDiv {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This centers the div in the middle of the page, but what if I want to add a div right next to it. In this div I would like to have a menu, a quote or something else. I didn't seem to get it to work after trying something with `position`.

Thanks in advance,

Boris

---

### Edit

To clarify what I mean, please look at this picture:

[image]

The big square is the 'main' centered div and then I would like a smaller div on the side of it.

Comment: A stupid solution I've found that works ok is to just place an invisible empty div on the right of the large div, give it the same dimensions as the small div on the left, and then center all three together (`text-align:center` on the parent). The "fake" div will push things back to center.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create your firstDiv as you are and then just put your right column inside the centered div and the position absolute it to the right like the following:

```css
.firstDiv {
  position:relative;

  width:300px;
  height:300px;

  margin: 0 auto;
  background:red;
    
    padding:10px;
}

.right-col {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:100%;

  width:100px;
  height:300px;

  background:blue;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstDiv">
    <div class="right-col">
        Menu / Quote
    </div>
    Middle div
</div>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QLYDs/

Make sure you have position relative on .firstDiv otherwise the positioning on .right-col won't work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `div`s in a section (or another block element), display them as `inline-block`s, and use `text-align` to have them centered.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
section{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>Blah</div>
    <div>Bouh</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is not what I mean. I want to have 1 'main' div that is centered on the page and then a smaller div just next to it.

Comment: @user3339355 Edit your question to make it clear then: add a quick drawing of what you'd want for instance.

Comment: Edited my question with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your best bet would be to set your page in columns. Do something like:

```css
colWrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
}
.column {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="colWrapper">
    <div class="column">1</div>
    <div class="column">2</div>
    <div class="column">3</div>
</div>
```

This way whatever you put in the 1 col would be on the left and the 3rd col would be right but col 2 would be in the center. You could get the `.offset()` if you wanted to do it with javascript.

heres a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FZ5DH/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `float` property on the one you want positioned next to the centered div. it's hard to give a precise answer without the rest of the HTML and css in context though. Another option would be to use the calc property... but that may be a bit trickier.